# Android Sent SMS Receiver Running Twice

Tags: android, sms

I am using loop to make android sent several message from json dataset, and use broadcast receiver to make log when the sms was successfully sent.

But somehow the log running more than once when i do that,
record 1 - logged once,
record 2 - logged twice,
record 3 - logged 3 times.

Why it behave like that?

here is my loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodeData.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject row = nodeData.getJSONObject(i);
            id = row.getInt("id");
            phone = row.getString("phone");
            message = row.getString("message");

            doSendMessage(phone, message);
        }
```

here is my send sms code

```
protected void doSendMessage(String phone, String message){
    String SENT = "Message Sent";
    String DELIVERED = "Message Delivered";

    MainActivity.phone = phone;
    MainActivity.message = message;

    Intent inSent = new Intent(SENT);
    Intent inDelivered = new Intent(DELIVERED);

    inSent.putExtra("exPhone", phone);
    inSent.putExtra("exMessage", message);

    PendingIntent piSent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, inSent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent piDelivered = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, inDelivered, 0);

    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1){    
            switch(getResultCode()){
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SMS Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Bundle extras = arg1.getExtras();               
                    if (extras != null) {
                      String exPhone = (String) extras.get("exPhone");
                      String exMessage = (String) extras.get("exMessage");
                      //Log.i("test_asd", exPhone + "-" + exMessage );
                      doSaveInOutbox(exPhone, exMessage);
                    }
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;                      
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1){
            switch(getResultCode()){
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS Delivered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS Not Delivered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;  
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phone, null, message, piSent, piDelivered);
}
```

Comment: Please try to provide a [smaller example](http://sscce.org/).  Does this still happen if you remove the SMS-specific code and just send broadcasts in this pattern?

Comment: it run once per iteration correctly if i am not put it on broadcast receiver. 

but since i have to check when the sms is sent or delivered, i need to put it on those receiver :(